# Добавить кнопку в приложение android

Tags: android, android-button

Как добавить в MainActivity кнопку с помощью Java? Нужен конкертный пример. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Идем в папку res/layouts там находим разметку нашей активности и добавляем кнопку приблизительно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button - Go to mkyong.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

дальше идем в класс активности и добавляем код для обработки нажатий на кнопку:

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent browserIntent = 
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

    });

}
```

[первоисточник](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/) с примером, [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button), [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681640/how-to-add-a-button-in-android) на enSO (англ версия сайта StackOverflow), [видеотуториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE5f1tV5nU4). Надеюсь у вас все получится. Удачи :)

Comment: В процессе работы программы должно создаваться несколько разных кнопок

Comment: Несколько кнопок можно создать несколько раз использовав один из вышеперечисленных вариантов.